# Issue using Ant Design ANTD with React

Tags: reactjs

I downloaded Ant design using `npm install --save antd`

then inside `index.js` I `import antd/dist/antd.css`

then inside `App.js` I `import {Table } from 'antd'`;

When I run `npm start` I got this

```
node_modules/@ant-design/icons-react/es/utils.js

Module not found: Can't resolve '@ant-design/colors' in 'C:\demoSpring\src\js\node_modules\@ant-design\icons-react\es'

Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'

Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'

Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

[Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8tuX.png)

Answer (score 7):

Add `@ant-design/colors` package.
Try executing the command `npm i @ant-design/colors`.
This should ideally solve your issue.

Comment: @RichardBrescher then upvote and accept the answer by ticking it off